# Create a new vector with same length as another and based on values of a third

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Existing data frame `ww` has two vectors, `X` and `Y`, both characters (this probably does not matter, but I just declare it).

Now I need: create a third vector `ZZ` in the same data frame `ww`, that is :

1. as long as `X` (I think i can use `length.out=length(x)`, but not sure how to structure it)
2. `Y` has four distinctive values (`"M1"`, `"M2"`, `"M3"`, `"M4"`). If `Y == "M1"` or `Y == "M4"` then `ZZ ="C"`. Else if `Y == "M2"` or `Y == "M3"` then `ZZ = "V"`.

Comment: If it is added to the same `data.frame`, it must be the same length; shorter, and it will be "recycled" (repeated) as long as it is a perfect divisor; longer, or not a perfect divisor, and you will get an error. I think the simplest/most-direct way for you to go is to use `ifelse` as shown in a couple answers. Other solutions certainly exist (using `dplyr`, `data.table` I'm sure, and more complicated can be contrived), but at your level of R I suggest going with direct/simple. (Not sure why the `[subset]` tag, this has nothing to do with subsetting your data.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to use factors:

```
dat$zz = factor(dat$Y, levels = c("M1", "M2", "M3", "M4"))
levels(dat$zz) = c('C', 'V', 'V', 'C')
```

Comment: This piece works for the narrow test on my hand. Not to criticize you, this one appears 'verbatim' way and requires enumeration and pairing.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `case_when` from the [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) package to create the `ZZ` column.

```
dat <- data.frame(X = c("a", "b", "c", 'd'),
                  Y = c("M1", "M2", "M3", "M4"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dat
#   X  Y
# 1 a M1
# 2 b M2
# 3 c M3
# 4 d M4

library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(ZZ = case_when(
    Y %in% c("M1", "M4")   ~ "C",
    Y %in% c("M2", "M3")   ~ "V",
    TRUE                   ~ NA_character_
  ))
dat2
#   X  Y ZZ
# 1 a M1  C
# 2 b M2  V
# 3 c M3  V
# 4 d M4  C
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R we can use the `ifelse` statement:

```
transform(dat,ZZ=ifelse(Y%in%c("M1","M4"),"C","V"))
  X  Y ZZ
1 a M1  C
2 b M2  V
3 c M3  V
4 d M4  C
```

or

```
dat$ZZ=ifelse(dat$Y%in%c("M1","M4"),"C","V")
dat
  X  Y ZZ
1 a M1  C
2 b M2  V
3 c M3  V
4 d M4  C
```

Comment: The first piece code : "Error in data.frame,...arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 218". Looks like I need to 'manually regulate' the length.

Comment: I do not understand

Comment: The second piece of code: dat$Y%in%c must be chopped down to Y%in%c. Otherwise got "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors". +: if, in here "M1","M4", I put some value that does not preexistin in Y, got a warning "Warning message:...Coercing LHS to a list". My problem is solved. Any thoughts on the messages?

Comment: even if I put a value that is not in Y eg: `ifelse(ww$Y%in%c("M1","M4","RT"),"C","V")`I still do get a solution `[1] "C" "V" "V" "C"`

Comment: That is probably not because you, not because me. That may be something with R. I told what I saw on the screen. Dead simple.

Comment: I restarted computer and Rstuio. Found <- somehow became =. Changed it back to <-. The error disappeared. However, the variable zz created in this way is not considered an Object in the data frame.

Comment: If you run the code I gave above in the solution what happens

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option just using `ifelse`

```
ww <- data.frame(X = c("a", "b", "c", 'd'),
                 Y = c("M1", "M2", "M3", "M4"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## Adding the ZZ column
ww2 <- cbind(ww,
             ZZ = ifelse(ww$Y %in% c("M1", "M4"), "C", "V"))
```

Note that in this case, `ZZ` takes the value `"V"` when `Y` is *not* `"M1"` or `"M4"` (assuming it can then only be `"M2"` or `"M3"`). For a safer but slower solution:

```
## Adding the empty ZZ column
ww2 <- cbind(ww, ZZ = rep("NA", nrow(ww)))
## Filling ZZ
ww2$ZZ <- ifelse(ww$Y %in% c("M1", "M4"), "C", NA)
ww2$ZZ <- ifelse(ww$Y %in% c("M2", "M3"), "V", NA)
```

Comment: I'm not sure. It might be a bit cumbersome since `with` will be better used for selecting the `ww2$ZZ` *a posterior* (e.g. `with(ww2, ZZ[Y %in% c("M1", "M2")])` should return only `C`s).